# I just can't insert more than 5 elements in a array in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a simple program where I declare the size of an array with one input, but I gives an IndexOutOfRange Exception if the array has more than 5 elements. Somebody can help me understand  why, please?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = new int[5];
        
        Console.WriteLine("Declare the array size");// 6
        int quant = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++)            {
            
            Console.WriteLine("Fill in the {0}º value ", i+1);
            
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            array[i] = number;
        }

        for (int i=0; i< quant; i++)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("\n", array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't do images of code here.  Post it as text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) We can't do anything at all with images of code. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: *Somebody can help me understand why, please?* - because you declared the array to have a length of 5 when you said `int[] array = new int[5];` - arrays do not expand, they have to be created anew with a bigger size and the old items copied over. If you want a collection that grows, use a `List<int>` (it uses an array internally, and does this newbigger-then-copy). At the very least, you should ask the user first how big they want the array, then make it to the size (`quant`) they gave - the way you have it now, you always set the array to 5 long, and ignore what they want

Comment: You created an array with length of 5 elements. Why don't you initialize it _after_ reading the desired size? `int[] array = new int[quant];`

Comment: It's also odd that you're declaring an array with a predetermined size *and then* asking the user for a size. You wouldn't be having this issue otherwise.

Comment: The other thing I wanted to point out; arrays have a `Length` property, which is always the Length of the array; you're asking for trouble if you have a variable that "stores how long the array is" and use it instead of just asking the array how long it is because they can go out of sync. As such, a pattern that iterates an array is `for(int x=0; x<array.Length; x++)` - we use `<` because an array of length 5 has valid indexes from 0 to 4

Comment: Thanks. how to declare an empty array that I can fill with as many elements as I want?

Comment: You can't with an array, because arrays do not expand. Use `var numbers = new List<int>()` then `numbers.Add(...)` to it. You can index it just like an array: `numbers[7]` gets the 8th item, but only if you have added at least 8 items. This is different to an array, which always has an 8th item if it was declared as any length longer than 7. In contast to an array's `Length`, lists have a `Count` property, which amounts to the same thing. They also have a `Capacity` property, which indicates how many iitems they can take before they autoexpand. They start at 16 and double each time they need

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array specifying the the number of elements after you read the input from the user. what you have done in your code is create an array of int with a size of 5. in case the user write a number larger then 5, you'll get the IndexOutOfRange exception.

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {        
      int quant = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int[] array = new int[quant ];

      for (int i = 0; i < quant; i++){
        Console.WriteLine("Fill in the {0}º value ", i+1);
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        array[i] = number;
      }

      for (int i=0; i< quant; i++){
        Console.WriteLine("\n", array[i]);
      }
    }
}
```

If you want to use an array without specifing a fixed limit, it's not possible in C# (in JS for instance it is). you can achieve this requirement in C# using a different type called `List` which represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index and does not require specifing a fixed size in initializtion (in contrast to array)

Read more about List - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0